# Solve gives odd answers

Tags: equation-solving

I am running this, and it should give me a number t with preferably many decimals, but the output is odd:

```
Solve[8/(t + 2)^2 + 2/(t + 1)^2 == 1, t, Reals]
```

Thank you

Comment: At first read documentation about `Solve`. It's normal output.

Comment: And use `Solve[8/(t+2)^2+2/(t+1)^2==1,t,Reals]//N[#,100]&` to see many decimals.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the linked question to understand what `Solve[]` is producing. If things remain unclear, edit your question to elaborate and we can reopen.

Comment: `Solve[8/(t + 2)^2 + 2/(t + 1)^2 == 1, t, Reals] // ToRadicals` gives explicit formulas for these quartic roots.